# ext4 in luks: how to calculate the minimum 'outer partition's size

Tags: luks

loop0p2 contains a luks2 that contains an ext4. The question is: how to calculate the minimum size the outer partition needs in order to hold the inner. Given is the size of the inner partition (in the example: 25614K)

```bsh
Device       Start   End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop0p1  2048  4095    2048    1M Microsoft basic data
/dev/loop0p2  4096 87273   83178 40,6M unknown
```

83178 Sectors (a 512 B) = 42587136 B

```bsh
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/loop0p2

Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
```

42587136 B - 16760832 B (luks2 overhead) = 25826304 B

25826304 B == 50442 sectors == 25221 KiB

```bsh
dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/test| grep -iE '^(block|inode) (count|size)' 
dumpe2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Inode count:              5232
Block count:              24567
Block size:               1024
Inode size:               128
```

inner partition:
128*5232 + 24567*1024 = 25156608 B = 24567 KiB

```bsh
resize2fs /dev/mapper/test 25614K
resize2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
The containing partition (or device) is only 25205 (1k) blocks.

You requested a new size of 25614 blocks.
```

25221 KiB - 25205 KiB = 16 KiB

So: the outer partition holds 41589 KiB, the luks overhead is 16368 KiB
Makes for the inner partition: 25221 KiB
Actual size of the inner partition seems to be: 24567 KiB.
The inner partition says, it cannot grow over 25205 KiB.

What is in the 16 KiB stored? Did I miscalculate the LUKS overhead? Is that something ext4 related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "extra" 16 KiB is secondary LUKS2 header. The "Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]" is size of the header, but you have two on the disk. See [LUKS2 On-Disk Format Specification](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/docs/on-disk-format-luks2.pdf) for more details.